# extract the images from rss feed

Tags: java, android, rss

I'm new to android development application and i suppose to parse rss url into a listview. the code is working but we want to extract the images from the rss feed and display it into the listview.

RssItem.java

```
public class RssItem {

// item title
private String title;
// item link
private String link;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}

}
```

ListListener.java

```
public class ListListener implements OnItemClickListener {

// List item's reference
List<RssItem> listItems;
// Calling activity reference
Activity activity;

public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
    listItems = aListItems;
    activity  = anActivity;
}

/**
 * Start a browser with url from the rss item.
 */
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));

    activity.startActivity(i);

}

}
```

RssParseHandler.java

```
 public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private List<RssItem> rssItems;

// Used to reference item while parsing
private RssItem currentItem;

// Parsing title indicator
private boolean parsingTitle;
// Parsing link indicator
private boolean parsingLink;

public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
}

public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
{
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem();
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
    } else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
            parsingLink = false;
        }
    }
}

}
```

RssReader.java

```
  public class RssReader {

private String rssUrl;

/**
 * Constructor
 * 
 * @param rssUrl
 */
public RssReader(String rssUrl) {
    this.rssUrl = rssUrl;
}

/**
 * Get RSS items.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<RssItem> getItems() throws Exception {
    // SAX parse RSS data
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    RssParseHandler handler = new RssParseHandler();

    saxParser.parse(rssUrl, handler);

    return handler.getItems();

}

}
```

ITCutiesReaderAppActivity.java

```
public class ITCutiesReaderAppActivity extends Activity {

// A reference to the local object
private ITCutiesReaderAppActivity local;

/**
 * This method creates main application view
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set reference to this activity
    local = this;

    GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

    // Start download RSS task
    task.execute("http://www.itcuties.com/feed/#sthash.YI6YrEet.dpuf");

    // Debug the thread name
    Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());
}

public class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
    @Override
    protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // Debug the task thread name
        Log.d("ITCRssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

        try {
            // Create RSS reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

            // Parse RSS, get items
            return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ITCRssReader", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {

        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView1);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>  (local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     result);
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set list view item click listener
        itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
    }
}  
}
```

Comment: So...what is your actual question? You expect us to read this overload of code and tell you exactly what to add or change? Can you at least bring it down to a few lines of code that would actually be relevant?

Comment: this code will only extract the title from the rss but i want to extract the images also into the listview.

Answer (score 2):

After reading online for a few hours I got this, originally the code didn't parse the image but after reading documentation on DOM elements (from the documentation that comes with Android Studio), I was able to create the following code snippet which actually works. I tested it in a console.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

/**
 * Created by user on 7/1/2016.
 */
public class FeedParser {
    // names of the XML tags
    static final String PUB_DATE = "pubDate";
    static final  String LINK = "link";
    static final  String TITLE = "title";
    static final  String ITEM = "item";
    static final  String IMAGE = "media:thumbnail";
    static final String AUTHOR = "author";

    final URL feedUrl;

    public FeedParser(String feedUrl){
        try {
            this.feedUrl = new URL(feedUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
            return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void parse() {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document dom = builder.parse(this.getInputStream());
            Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList items = root.getElementsByTagName(ITEM);
            for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){

                Node item = items.item(i);
                NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0;j<properties.getLength();j++){
                    Node property = properties.item(j);
                    String name = property.getNodeName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(TITLE)){
                        System.out.println(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(LINK)){
                        System.out.println(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(AUTHOR)){
                        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                        NodeList chars = property.getChildNodes();
                        for (int k=0;k<chars.getLength();k++){
                            text.append(chars.item(k).getNodeValue());
                        }
                        System.out.println(text.toString());
                    } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(PUB_DATE)){
                        System.out.println(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
                    }
                    else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(IMAGE)){
                        System.out.println(property.getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getNodeValue());
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] aeg){
    new FeedParser("http://www.pcworld.com/index.rss").parse();
    }
}
```

Though my answer is late i hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 1):

You are reinventing the wheel. You can simplify everything by using the [android-rss](https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss) library with my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library (originally posted [here](http://gist.github.com/phil-brown/6178243)):

```
final RSSHandler handler = new RSSHandler(new RSSConfig());
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url(options.url())
                        .type("GET")
                        .dataType("XML")
                        .context(this)
                        .SAXContentHandler(handler)
                        .success(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
                                RSSFeed feed = handler.feed();
                                List<RSSItem> = feed.getItems();
                                //use this list to update your list adapter, then call the method "getThumbnails()" to get the images associated with the feed item.
                            }
                        }));
```

Comment: @user2870902 this code replaces the code you have. place it in your `Activity`, then create a new `ArrayAdapter` of `RSSItem`s as your `ListView` adapter, and simply put the data received into this adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: i appreciate your help, but can you give me an example because i am new to android

Comment: @user2870902, look around *StackOverflow* for an example of this. One points to [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx) example.